# No JSF support in IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4

Tags: java, jsf, intellij-idea, ide

The facts:

- IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4 Ultimate (Educational Use)
- Java EAR with Web Module
- Wildfly Application Server
- Primefaces 5.0

I just can't find any support for JSF in my IntelliJ IDE. There is no JSF option in the *View -> Tool Windows* menu as shown in several tutorials. I can't add a JSF facet in the *Module Settings*. I added the schemas and URIs of tag libs manually but code completion does not work either.

Did I miss something? Is it possible to add support for it in the installation process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

*File -> Settings -> Plugins -> enable JSF plugin*

jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp10.5/enabling-jsf-support.html

Answer (score 0):

[Find here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/javaserver_faces.html) all the info.

> IntelliJ IDEA features the support for JavaServer Faces (JSF) technology that leverages existing, standard UI and Web-tier concepts without limiting developers to a particular mark-up language, protocol, or client device through custom tag library for expressing a JavaServer Faces interface within a JSP page.

- [Preparing developement](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/preparing-for-jsf-application-development.html).
- [Facets](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/jsf-facet-page.html).

I guess you don't have the correct configuration in `Facelets support` option:

> Select the required Facelets support option.
>   This is the project-level setting. The selected option is set for all modules in the current project.
>
> **Auto.** Automatic Facelets detection. The XHTML files are treated as Facelets or ordinary XHTML files depending on whether the module has a JSF facet or not. In the modules that have a JSF facet, all XHTML files are considered Facelets. If a module does not have a JSF facet, all XHTML files in it are treated as ordinary XHTML files.
>   **Enabled.** All XHTML files in the project are treated as Facelets.
>   **Disabled. All XHTML files in the project are considered not to be Facelets and are treated as ordinary XHTML files.**

**UPDATE:** to enable Facelets support [check this part of the manual](http://jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp10.5/enabling-jsf-support.html).

Comment: But where do I find the Facelets support option?

Comment: nice to hear... hope it solves your question! updated answer to clarify